# How many marbles must be placed in a square area of $16 in^2$ to ensure that two of the marbles are within $2 \sqrt{2}$ inches of each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry

How many marbles must be placed in a square area of $16 in^2$ to ensure that two of the marbles are within $2 \sqrt{2}$ inches of each other?

Wouldn't even know how to begin this question.

Comment: Begin figuring out the length of the side of that square area. (And then figuring out what $2\sqrt2\,\textrm{in}$ mean)

Comment: HINT: It’s a pigeonhole principle problem. Divide the square into smaller regions whose diameters are at most $2\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  How big is the square?  Imagine dividing it into squares with diagonal $2 \sqrt 2$-how big are those squares?  Then think about the pigeonhole principle.  This gives an upper bound-it does not prove that a smaller number will not suffice.  I don't have an answer for a good lower bound.

Comment: For a lower bound: put a marble in each corner of the original square.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 5. This can be done by showing that 4 does not satisfy the conditions in only one case: the marbles are on the midpoints of the sides.

Placing a fifth marble will result in one of these distances becoming less than $2\sqrt{2}$.